# Rails - How to disallow specific inputs in model validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, routes

My User model has an attribute called `:profile_name` which is used in routing profile page url's   - `domain.com/:profile_name` . In order to prevent collision with my other views I want to make sure a User can't choose something like "friends" or "feed" as their profile name. How can I set this in validations?

/models/user.rb (currently):

```
...
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
validates :profile_name, presence: true,
                       uniqueness: true,
                       format: {
                         with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/,
                         message: 'Must be formatted correctly.'
                       }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`exclusion` validation helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#exclusion):

```
validates :profile_name, presence: true,
                         ...,
                         exclusion: {
                           in: ["friends", "feed"],
                           message: "Profile name %{value} is reserved."
                         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom validation method.  You'd probably want to separate out the forbidden list, but I kept this extra concise.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :profile_not_forbidden

 protected

  def profile_not_forbidden
    if ['friends','feed'].include?(profile_name) 
      errors.add(:profile_name, 'Forbidden profile name.')
    end    
  end 

end
```

Comment: I didn't know about 'exclusion' in the built ins, obviously.  Nice!  I was going to delete this inferior answer--but maybe a pointer to the custom approach could still help somebody with a similar question in a more complicated circumstances.